# mysql self join returning blank values

Tags: mysql, self-join

I have the following mysql query

---

```
select a.agency_name, a.green ,b.red, c.amber
from (select count(action_status) as green, agency_name from tbl_actions
where action_status='In Progress' group by agency_name) a
join (select count(action_status) as red, agency_name from tbl_actions
where action_status='Delayed' group by agency_name) b on a.agency_name=b.agency_name
join (select count(action_status) as amber, agency_name from tbl_actions
where act_status='Completed' group by agency_name) c on a.agency_name=c.agency_name
```

---

and it is returning blank values as
[image: blank values]

I do have these fields in the db populated with relevant data.

Comment: Would you please format your query, so we can read it?

Comment: This query will work only if there is atleast one row for each type of `act_status` per `agency_name`

Comment: There are no blank values, that's an empty result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is much simpler:

```
select a.agency_name,
       sum(a.action_status = 'In Progress') as green,
       sum(a.action_status = 'Delayed') as red,
       sum(a.action_status = 'completed') as amber
from tbl_actions a
group by a.agency_name;
```

A self-join is not necessary.  The reason you are getting no rows in the result set is because no agency has all three statuses.